# MXSegmentedPager initial page

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, selectedindex, segmentedcontrol

I have a MXSegmentedPager with 4 pages. How can I set the initial page to display.
I tried the following line but it only changes the segmented control's selected index. Displayed page does not change. Im know It's an easy question but could not find anything.

```
self.segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
```

MXSegmentedPager lib:
https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me , if  called `[segmentedPager.pager.showPage(at: 4, animated: false)` in **viewDidAppear** and it is moving both the segmented control and the page properly. It does not work in viewWillAppear

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if(isfromCard){
        segmentedPager.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4
        segmentedPager.pager.showPage(at: 4, animated: false)
        segmentedPager.pager.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: how to set view controller for the segment ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
[self.segmentedPager.pager showPageAtIndex:4 animated:NO];
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c".